# How to escape SQL parameter in JDBC when PreparedStatement won't work?

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, escaping, postgresql-9.4

I have a string that I want to pass to SQL. To prevent SQL injection and other quoting and escaping problems, the best practice is to use a `PreparedStatement` with `?`.  For example:

```
val ps = conn.prepareStatement("select * from foo where name = ?")
ps.setString(1, name)
```

But for some SQL code, this won't work. For example, here is PostgreSQL, trying to create a view.

```
 val ps = conn.prepareStatement("create temp view v1 as select * from foo where name = ?")
 ps.setString(1, name)
 val rs = ps.execute()
```

This throws an error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: there is no parameter $1
```

It apparently doesn't allow parameters to `create view`. How do you get around this and safely escape the string?

Comment: Perhaps you should just use a `Statement` instead of a `PreparedStatement`?

Comment: How would that help me escape `name`? I'd have to concatenate it into the string and then I'm open to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: I see what you mean. Sorry, I should have looked more closely at what you were trying to do before I commented. I have since tried a few variations but they all result in the same error you receive. It seems that PostgreSQL really doesn't like parameter substitution in DDL, even when trying to invoke it from a Function.

Answer (score 0):

Prepared statements are used to plan a complex statement once and then execute it multiple (= very many) times with different parameter values. Simple statements have no noticeable benefit from using a prepared statement because planning them is trivial. DDL statements are not supported at all, so that is most likely the cause of the error, although the error message is confusing.

From the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-prepare.html):

> PREPARE name [ ( data_type [, ...] ) ] AS **statement**
>
> ***statement***
>
> Any SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or VALUES statement.

The `PreparedStatement` class does document that you can use DDL in the `executeUpdate()` method, but from a logical standpoint that is just nonsense, at least in PostgreSQL.

Instead, you should use a `Statement` and then call `execute()` or `executeUpdate()` (a bit odd that the latter method would support DDL statements because there is no update being performed).

**Preventing SQL-injection**

In order to prevent SQL-injection you can use a few PostgreSQL functions:

- `quote_literal()` - As can be expected, this will quote a literal parameter value to be safe in the query. Not only does this prevent you from [Bobby Tables](http://www.bobby-tables.com), but also from the likes of `Mr. O'Brien`.
- `quote_nullable()` - For literals like above, but will generate proper code when the parameter `IS NULL`.
- `quote_identifier()` - Will double quote any table or column name that might cause problems for the planner, like table name `from` with columns `int`, `type` and `from`: `SELECT int, type, from FROM from WHERE int = type` becomes `SELECT "int", "type", "from" FROM "from" WHERE "int" = "type"`.

You can use these functions directly in your SQL statements and then let PostgreSQL deal with nasty input.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but my main problem is that I want to escape that string to prevent quoting problems and SQL injection. I should have made that more clear in my question. I will update it.  I don't see how `Statement` will help me escape the `name` parameter.

Comment: The functions you mention (`quote_literal`, etc) don't help here. I'm in application code, calling JDBC API. The string parameter needs to be protected from SQL injection before it ever reaches any PostgreSQL functions like `quote_literal`.